# I'd like to implement a function sending message with popup window like Gmail and facebook

Tags: javascript, jquery, python

[image]

I tried to search the way to implement that kind of function, but I had no idea how to search owing to my poor English.
If you know the web site or library of the function, would you please let me know?

I use `python3`, `jQuery2.2`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use a plugin for this functionality. All you need is some `div` in your HTML that would contain your "popup window", CSS to position it correctly and a couple lines of jQuery to hide and show.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.toggler').on('click', function(){
    $('.popup-window').toggle();
  })
});
```

```css
.popup-window {
  position: absolute;
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  bottom: 0px;
  right: 10px;
  
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button class="toggler">Show/Hide</button>

<div class="popup-window">
  Your content, but better styled :)
</div>
```

No need to clatter up your project with ton of unnecessary plugin files.

Answer (score 1):

Gmail is developed in a set of tools called Google Closure. It helps you write web applications and can transpile your code into different JavaScript dialects.

Find out more - https://developers.google.com/closure/

Comment: Thank you, I will study Google Closure. Thank you for letting me know.